# How to add our own POI using metaio SDK

Tags: android, augmented-reality, metaio, junaio

I am trying to integrate metaio SDK in my application for augmented reality.

I have gone through this: http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/location-based-ar/, but I am still not able to add my own POI.

Could anyone who has integrated the metaio SDK give me an idea how to add my own POI?

Comment: Any one integrated Metaio SDK for android?

Comment: Have you managed to do that?

Comment: Yes i did it and working fine...

Comment: Do you mind sharing something, answering your own question? I'm not getting it

Comment: OK no problem, but it is in Android(Java) is it OK for you?

Comment: Yes, no problem. I'm following the steps just like the tutorials but don't get it working =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have add the poi in loadContents() method..like below

```
      private IRadar mRadar;
private IBillboardGroup mBillBoardGroup;
private ArrayList<GeometryBundle> geometriesList;

IGeometry one = metaioSDK.createGeometryFromImage(createBillboardTexture("Test","http://www.abc.org/150.jpg","0.05 miles"), true);
one.setTranslationLLA(new LLACoordinate(24.463729,54.385650, 0, 5));        
geometriesList.add(new GeometryBundle(one, "http://www.abc.org/151.jpg"));

// create radar
    mRadar = metaioSDK.createRadar();
    mRadar.setBackgroundTexture(AssetsManager.getAssetPath("Tutorial5/Assets5/radar.png"));
    mRadar.setObjectsDefaultTexture(AssetsManager.getAssetPath("Tutorial5/Assets5/yellow.png"));
    mRadar.setRelativeToScreen(IGeometry.ANCHOR_TL);

    mBillBoardGroup = this.metaioSDK.createBillboardGroup();

    for (GeometryBundle test : geometriesList) {
        mRadar.add(test.geometry);
        mBillBoardGroup.addBillboard(test.geometry);
    }
```

After this create a class GeometryBundle and create constructor with parameters...

Comment: i've same problem, but if i have not any image?

Comment: My mistake sorry, i forgot to attach the .obj.

Comment: link has been failed